# Keep the pervious step open Vertical Stepper Material-UI

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, uistepper, stepper

Trying to implement a vertical stepper and keep the previous step open when I move the next one. I tried to use expanded on`StepContent` but it opens all the steps.
I would appreciate some insight on how to fix keep it open.
I added the example of the code on [code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/bold-snowflake-7nktx?file=/src/App.js:2251-2262)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the `active` property on the `Step` itself.  For your case add something like

```
<Step key={label} active={index === activeStep - 1 || index === activeStep}>
```

to keep the previous step open.